# Wordpress post/pages not publishing immediately -> missed schedule instead

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, centos

I experienced strange behaviour of wordpress. Whenever I want to publish a post or page it says "Missed schedule". But I have no intention to schedule. I want to publish something directly.

Some times later (I assume when wp-cron runs) the pages gets published. But this bahaviour is immense problem for me developing the page, as the customizer crashes and is not able to update changes. Usually a "immediately" published post should be published, well, immediately. Never had this issue before on other systems. I do not need the scheduling function at all, but now I am forced to schedule anything?

Setup:
CentOS 7, PHP 7.4, Apache 2.4, MySQL (Fresh Setup of the LAMP Server) Als tried PHP 7.3/MariaDB.
Installation of latest wordpress 5.5.1 without any issues (but also tests with older versions caused the problem)
Check of Servertime vs. Wordpress timezone - everything fine here
Standard Theme adter installation, no plugins active!
Checked the rights for apache user, everything fine (755/644)
Checked the "run wp cron" plugins, but thats not solving the issue.

I assume there is some problem with wp-cron or the db but most probably my server setup is missing some dependency/configuration? (But I tried different Tutorials for installation, so must be something very basic...)

Somehow it seems like nobody every experienced this issue, as I googled for hours... Hopefully sombody with more backend experience can explain whats happening here and how to fix it.

[Here is a picutre of how the workflow looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IHJE.png)

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-missed-schedule/

Comment: Thanks for this comment, unfortunately it is quite unqualified and does not help anyone, because 1. I never have the intention to schedule a post. 2. the known methods have already been tested - without success. This was also described in my post.

Comment: I was just addressing your comment *"Somehow it seems like nobody every experienced this issue, as I googled for hours."* https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB820GB820&ei=QCdRX-GuO5HbsAewpJrQDQ&q=wordpress+missed+schedule&oq=wordpress+missed+schedule&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxAzoHCAAQsQMQQzoFCC4QsQM6CAgAELEDEJECUMUlWK47YL88aABwAHgAgAFxiAHFDZIBBDI0LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjhztzpwM3rAhWRLewKHTCSBtoQ4dUDCA0&uact=5 have you tried disabling `WP_CRON` and adding your own cron job?

Comment: The thing is, I do not want to add a cronjob at all. I want to immediately publish the post/page. All issues adressed so far are problems with intentionally scheduled posts. Sorry, I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing without schedule Wordpress will publish it unless something prevents it from happening.
There is a known issue where if you use localhost server may have issues with Gutenberg so for test purpose try https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ and see if its fixing it for you. If it does its probably a problem with your server settings preventing the rest api to work or issue with wp-cron.php.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint,

I tried it like this with the Plugin "Classic Editor". Unfortunately it does not solve the problem. 
After clicking on "Publish" you get the feedback that the page was created. In fact this is not the case and in the overview you can find it again as "missed schedule". The plugin "Disable Gutenberg" does not even allow me to publish immediately (The Dropdown in the box on the side only has the options for "scheduled", "pending review" and "draft").

More ideas what else can prevent "publish immediately"?

Comment: Are you able to access the rest api ? for example yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts ? Can you see is it evrything working properly with https://bg.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ ? You can use https://bg.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ to see what is happening for some errors that may put some light.

Comment: Also is it local machine ? Can you try with desktopserver ?

Comment: Wordpress rest api is enabled and accessible (.../?rest_route=/). I noticed three things: 1. wp_cache is disabled 2. the server header is set to "expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT" 3. when I want to publish a page and activate "immediately", the confirmation is not "The page is now online" but "The page is scheduled for [current date, to the second]". It is not a local machine, it is a virtual server.

Comment: Mmm i cant tell what might be the issue there but deff its not the wordpress by its self. I still think there is some settgins on your server that maight couse this issue. Could you try atleast this method ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281571/future-to-publish-into-postmeta/281572 Its changing the status of your post to published. Its not perfect solution but untill you find the problem. Im sorry i cant give you more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with all installations of WP in a VPS.
No useful info on google.
Somebody has find a workarround: change Centos+plesk to Ubuntu+Plesk. This seems to work fine.

I have finally found a solution to the problem. Changing the system is not a useful option for me.

In this forum they explain the problem: [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371454/error-trying-to-publish-immediately-post-status-future-missed-schedule-error)

And it brings us an explanation in the plesk forums: [here](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/utc-time-issue-plesk-php-7-3-7-4-on-centos7.356169/)

It is basically a problem in CentOS7, the UTC file is not valid and this causes problems in publishing changes in WordPress.

The problem is solved by replacing that file "/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC" with a correct copy (I have taken it from another server with CentOS6).

And everything works correctly.
You don't even need to reboot.

Comment: Yes, I also switched to ubuntu. This works fine, but still no idea whats causing the issue with CentOS, maybe some SELinux thing...

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and got this issue. I have no idea what to do.